# Broken external USB hard drive undetected by system

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, forensics

I have an external 1TB Intenso® USB hard drive, which stopped working after a small crash on the case. When I plug it into any computer, the light comes on and it makes noise (you can feel the disk running), but the volume is not detected anymore.
On GNU/Linux, `dmesg` displays these lines when the disk is plugged:

```
[ 3453.185834] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 3453.210198] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0701
[ 3453.210207] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3453.210212] usb 3-2: Product: External USB 3.0
[ 3453.210217] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Intenso
[ 3453.210221] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 20140824012094
[ 3453.210763] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3453.211264] scsi host9: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
```

But strangely, neither `fdisk -l` nor `lsblk` nor any tool I know is able to detect the disk and partitions. I can't use `dd` or any forensic tool I know, because they all require either an iso image, either a device path, which I can't provide because the system *doesn't* detect this external hard drive.

- Is there any way to detect the partition table, the filesystems or any data located on this drive ?

**EDIT:**

As asked in comments, I will explain what happens if I remove the disk from its case and connect it directly to the motherboard, without the SATA bridge:

It still make noise at the beginning, then no sound. It seems to turn, but I am not sure.

*(by the way, I tested the SATA bridge with another working hdd I own, and it worked correctly)*

`dmesg` displays these lines when plugging via computer's SATA port:

```
[   73.808715] ata6: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0000 action 0xe frozen
[   73.808724] ata6: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[   73.808730] ata6: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[   73.808739] ata6: hard resetting link
[   83.820127] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[   83.820138] ata6: hard resetting link
[   93.850117] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[   93.850128] ata6: hard resetting link
[  104.850288] ata6: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  128.880166] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  128.880178] ata6: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[  128.880182] ata6: hard resetting link
[  134.070082] ata6: softreset failed (device not ready)
[  134.070093] ata6: reset failed, giving up
[  134.070104] ata6: EH complete
```

In the `smartctl` manpage, I can read:

> The user must specify the device to be controlled or interrogated as
>   the final argument to smartctl

I cannot use smartctl or any tool which require path to device, since I haven't any path to give.

Comment: You can try to open the case, check the cables inside, and if it still doesn't work, remove the hdd and connect it to a desktop pc (or buy another case without disk).

Comment: @andrewq AFAIK "brand" USB drives have specific electronics, they aren't built with a USB controller slapped over a plain SATA drive (I tried your suggestion once and it didn't work out as intended because of this).

Comment: First step is to take the USB-to-SATA bridge out of the equation: Open the enclosure, remove the hard disk proper, connect it up to SATA. Then, run `smartctl` and see what you get. `smartctl` may or may not work via USB, it depends on the bridge.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it didn't resolve my issue. I added an edit to answer your suggestions.

Comment: @JakeGould He has been underpowered for a while, and he may have fallen several times.

Comment: With all you have presented JakeGould is probably right and your drive is simply dead because it's physically damaged. It might be possible that you're actually damaging it further with every spin up. If you're interested in recovering the data you will likely have to find a professional partner and spend money on it.

Comment: @xenoid if you don't open the enclosure and see what's inside...

Comment: Yes, but this answers a comment that implies there is always a bridge. If a misinformed user rips off the electronics thinking it is only the bridge, the disk will be dead for good.